# Need help in understanding some SQL logic using PIVOT, COLEASE, and CAST

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, coalesce

I needed to figure out how to Pivot a set of data I had, and the code works as needed, but the issue is that I don't really understand why that is. Can anyone help out a rookie and explain exactly why the code below decided to 'SELECT @columns = COALESCE + ...

Why does he specifiy two arguments in the COALESCE function? Is it just to return all of the columns in that table? If so, can someone break down exactly how it does that. I'm pulling this code from this website as reference: ( http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php )

Thanks in advance!

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(Variable as varchar) + ']',
'[' + cast(Variable as varchar)+ ']')
FROM #temp123
GROUP BY Variable


DECLARE @query VARCHAR(8000)

SET @query = '
SELECT *
FROM #temp123
PIVOT
(
MAX(VaribleValue)
FOR [Variable]
IN (' + @columns + ')
)
AS p'

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the structure of the code I can see that the query is designed for a dynamic PIVOT, which means that the number of columns can vary; unlike a traditional [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in which you have to specify the exact columns to pivot for

The [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) keyword is similar to the [ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms184325%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) function, but the main differences is that you can specify multiple values to check for:

So for example you can use `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 1, NULL) AS [Output];` The value of [Output] will be 1. It is the same as saying, if the first value is NULL; return the next; if the second value is NULL; use the third; and so on until the first NON-NULL value is found.

So in your case, the `COALESCE` keyword will check the `@columns` variable appended to the `Variable` field; if it is NULL (which can occur if any value in the `Variable` field is NULL) then it will simply use the next statement.

Comment: but what I don't understand is doesn't that create some type of weird infinite loop? Select '@columns = COALESCE(@columns... 

as in he's using @columns in his definition of @columns? plus, why does he append the '@columns' to the front of the variable anyway?

is this simply just going to return me a record set of what columns are being returned for when Variable <> NULL?

Comment: No, The COALESCE will recognise that '@columns' IS NULL to begin with, therefore setting the '@columns' to the second value. If '@columns' IS NOT NULL (set to have a value at another part of the code) then the '[' + cast(Variable as varchar)+ ']' will be appended to the end of @columns. This is put in there because you a building a string, and the thing with strings is that by default CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is set to ON, which means that if you concat any value with a NULL, a NULL value will result. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx for more info.

Comment: Thanks @BorhanMooz, does this mean that the first argument was put in to automatically have the coalesce go to the second value? Since as you mentioned it'll be treated as a NULL and when a NULL is appended then a NULL value will result, therefore forcing it always to the second one?

Comment: hmm ... so then why the coalesce at all? would it have worked the same if I took out to coalesce all together and just put in the second argument?

Comment: In your particular case, yes. But say in a scenario where '@columns' is set-up in multiple parts of the same procedure, this will make sure that if at another point the '@columns' variable is set to NULL, then it doesn't affect the variable's value at this current spot. Try both versions, one with and one without the COALESCE and see the effects it has.

Comment: Ps, if the answer was correct, please accept it as the answer.